# .NET 5.0 and ADO.NET model

Tags: visual-studio, ado.net, .net-5

I read somewhere that .NET 5.0 supported ADO.NET EF model (.edmx file) (as the earlier Core versions did not).
In a .NET 5.0 project the item template is present, but when I choose it I get an error stating that the EF runtime assemblires are not found for this target framework.

[image]

[image]

Does anyone know if this is supported or not?

Comment: "as the earlier Core versions did not". That couldn't be possibly more incorrect. The entire Entity Framework Core library is based on ADO.NET, if not a hundred more libraries. As for the Visual Studio template, the item you're selecting most likely corresponds to .NET Framework templates as I can also see EF 5 templates in your screenshot and that's obviously not supported outside .NET Framework.

Comment: Sorry, that was inaccurate. I meant the ADO.NET EF model (edmx file). To my knowledge that was not supported. I'll update the post

Comment: EDMX died together with Entity Framework AFAIK. I don't see anything even remotely similar in the EF Core 5 plan: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/plan

Comment: Can't find the link now, but I'm sure I read somewhere that is was back with 5.0. I may be wrong, most likely. Thanks for the information. Think I'll scrap my edmx plans ;)

Comment: There's so much confusion (you can see questions here in SO) between .NET Framework. .NET Core and .NET 5, that I wouldn't be surprised if you had read something about EF 5 rather than EF Core 5 :) Generally, try to stick to Microsoft Docs for source of truth

Comment: Thanks again @CamiloTerevinto

Comment: I'd say that EDMX died long before EF. It dwindled when Code First was introduced in EF 4.1 and died soon after. The double-model approach didn't work in the vast majority of cases with developers having to create and edit the exact same mappings twice. This eliminated the benefits of the UI designer. Besides, the "domain" model EDMX was supposed to provide is the model used by the application's *code*, not the one provided by the ORM. You should be able to use the same domain classes even if you switch ORMs.

Comment: [EntityDeploy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/what-is-new/#ef-designer-support) was added in .net core 3.1 to support EDMX files with EF6